# Is the verb "cast" in acting, metalworking and programming the same verb?

Tags: verbs, technical, programming

- An actor is "cast" in a role: Jane Lee is cast as "Jo Smith".
- A sculpture is "cast" in bronze: molten bronze is poured into a mould.
- A variable is "cast" as a certain type of information in programming: is `1` the number one, or a string consisting of the character `'1'`? You "cast" it to resolve that problem.

Are these all the same verb at the root?

Here are the relevant verb definitions from [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cast):

> 1 [usually with adverbial of direction] chiefly literary Throw (something) forcefully in a specified direction: *he cast the book down on to the chair angrily the fishermen cast a large net around a school of tuna figurative individuals who do not accept the norms are cast out from the group*
>
> 4 Shape (metal or other material) by pouring it into a mould while molten: *when hammered or cast, bronze could be made into tools*
>
> 4.2 Arrange and present in a specified form or style: *he issued statements cast in tones of reason*
>
> [unnumbered, noun] The actors taking part in a play, film, or other production: *he draws sensitive performances from his inexperienced cast*

Here's a definition from [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/cast) for cast as a verb in relation to actors:

> 4 a  : to assign roles for (a play, movie, etc.) to actors. *cast a play*
> b  : to assign (an actor or actress) a role in a film, play, etc. *She was cast as a college professor who becomes a spy.*

Comment: Which dictionaries have you checked in?

Comment: The phantom upvoter fingers their nose at site policy yet again.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I found the question interesting enough to add the definitions myself. (I wasn't the phantom up-voter but have up-voted after adding the dictionary definitions.)

Comment: I'll note that I've never read any explanation of why the term was chosen for it's programming sense.  (And likely the people who would know are dead.)  There's a good chance, though, that the term may have had a pre-existing mathematical sense.

Comment: @HotLicks Likely first used in C in 1973 to indicate the operation of making a variable of one type into another, i.e, from one role to another, thus *casting*, perhaps in the acting sense, perhaps in the sense of "cast in a different light."  The language is Dennis Ritchie's baby, and he's still alive.  The predecessor to C was B.  It had no such operation. Algol 68 preceded C but called this mechanism *coercion*.

Comment: @deadrat - If I had to guess, I'd choose either the sense of tossing dice, or the sense of casting metal into a new shape (though I can see that casting into a role could make sense as well).  It's complicated by the fact that "cast", in C and it's successors, actually refers to two distinctly different operations.  (This has been a source of confusion since Day One.)

Comment: @deadrat - And Ritchie died 5 years ago.

Comment: @Lawrence But the question isn't answered by the different definitions per se, but by the fact that they're listed under the same headword. The [otherwise fine] answer below is genref.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree the definitions I added don't answer the question - that makes the core of the question *not* genref. I added the definitions to avoid having the otherwise-good and *interesting* question getting closed for *lack of research*. I also agree the [answer below](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/315463/142322) (in its current form) doesn't answer the question, but that also doesn't invalidate the *question*.

Comment: @HotLicks My error.  Ritchie lives on only in my memory.  But Ken Thompson can probably tell you.  If he would deign to talk to hoi polloi.

Comment: @Lawrence How can you agree that Josh61's answer doesn't answer the question when I say '[It's] fine' [apart from being a straight quote from a single well-known resource listed in the Help Center]?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps I misunderstood you. This is my reading of [your comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315460/is-the-verb-cast-in-acting-metalworking-and-programming-the-same-verb?noredirect=1#comment716003_315460): "But ... per se" = showing definitions *alone* (cf per se) doesn't answer the question; "but ... headword" = all the definitions do is show the same *root* for the various usages; "The ... genref" = Josh61's answer would be ok, except that it only provides genref (i.e. it needs more than genref to answer the question fully). (cont'd)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth (cont'd) When I agreed with that understanding, I was agreeing that the OP asks for more than *just* genref - the OP is after the etymology of *cast* as used in programming, and how it parallels that of the meaning of the word in the other contexts. The dictionary definitions just provide a starting point for that discussion. They certainly *don't* answer the question fully.

Comment: @Lawrence It is expected that those asking questions on etymology check in and, where relevant and not the complete answer, quote the Online Etymology Dictionary. It is also expected that people here with say 20k+ rep close-vote answers lacking basic research rather than supplying it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth (cont'd 2) Rereading your comment, I can see you intended "but by" (in clause 2) to mean "the question *is* answered by" in contrast to clause 1, rather than "except for the following portion", i.e. "the only part of the question it answers". Likewise, your "[otherwise fine]" was probably intended to mean "it *does* answer the question, but I don't like the extensive quote". My intent with this comment is not to put words into your mouth, but simply to acknowledge that your earlier comment can be read consistently with your later one(s).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Re [your comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315460/is-the-verb-cast-in-acting-metalworking-and-programming-the-same-verb?noredirect=1#comment716554_315460) - feel free to add to the OP's question to improve it. That you are *encouraged* to edit in this way is [official *policy*](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) for 2K+ rep users (bullet point 4) rather than mere opinion. Where's the *official policy* expecting (not just *permitting* or even *encouraging*) 20k+ or so rep users to "close-vote ... rather than supplying it" as you suggest?

Answer (score 4):

***[Cast](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cast)*** is a prolific term with tens of different meanings, the root appears to be the same one:

> - c. 1200, "to throw, fling, hurl," from a Scandinavian source akin to Old Norse kasta "to throw" (cognate with Swedish kasta, Danish kaste, North Frisian kastin), of uncertain origin.
> - Meaning "to form in a mold" is late 15c. In the sense of "warp, turn" it replaced Old English weorpan (see warp (v.)), and itself largely has been superseded now by throw, though ***cast still is used of fishing lines and glances. Meaning "calculate, find by reckoning; chart (a course)" is from c. 1300.***
> - ***The sense of "a throw" carried an idea of "the form the thing takes after it has been thrown," which led to widespread and varied meanings, such as "group of actors in a play" (1630s).***
> - ***OED finds 42 distinct noun meaning and 83 verbal ones***, with many sub-definitions. ***Many of the figurative senses converged in a general meaning "sort, kind, style" (mid-17c.).*** A cast in the eye (early 14c.) preserves the older verbal sense of "warp, turn."

(Etymonline)

Comment: What is the relevance of bolding *cast still is used of fishing lines and glances*? I believe the "meaning calculate" is significant to the cast a variable meaning, whatever that means. If  a computer programming term hadn't been also included, I'd be tempted to dig deeper myself. I suspect *cast* is similar to *run* and *set* which have dozens and dozens of different meanings.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I was making an answer but someone started screaming, shouting , down-and-close voting...I gave up and forgot about it.

Comment: Well it's still open, make the most of it. The question is also mentioned on meta